# Angular UI Grid API doesn't work in capturing last cell edit

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I want to show and capture last cell edited, but it doesn't work like at provided [example in official docs](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable)

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong or fork [my plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/W00Gk4a6tGNWbjwjaSEX?p=preview) and provide a link to working example?

I'm using AngularUI Grid 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep `$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi` inside the controller. Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqxWrRSkfQKzNYHRZSI2?p=preview) out.